# Using cpquery function for several pairs from dataset

Tags: r, for-loop, bnlearn

I am relatively beginner in R and trying to figure out how to use cpquery function for bnlearn package for all edges of DAG.

First of all, I created a *bn* object, a *network* of bn and a *table* with all strengths.

```
library(bnlearn)
data(learning.test)
baynet = hc(learning.test)
fit = bn.fit(baynet, learning.test)
sttbl = arc.strength(x = baynet, data = learning.test)
```

Then I tried to create a new variable in *sttbl* dataset, which was the result of cpquery function.

```
sttbl = sttbl %>% mutate(prob = NA) %>% arrange(strength)
sttbl[1,4] = cpquery(fit, `A` == 1, `D` == 1)
```

It looks pretty good (especially on bigger data), but when I am trying to automate this process somehow, I am struggling with errors, such as:

> Error in sampling(fitted = fitted, event = event, evidence = evidence,  : 
>     logical vector for evidence is of length 1 instead of 10000.

In perfect situation, I need to create a function that fills the *prob* generated variable of *sttbl* dataset regardless it's size. I tried to do it with for loop to, but stumbled over the error above again and again. Unfortunately, I am deleting failed attempts, but they were smt like this:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(sttbl)) {
     j = sttbl[i,1]
     k = sttbl[i,2]
     sttbl[i,4]=cpquery(fit, fit$j %in% sttbl[i,1]==1, fit$k %in% sttbl[i,2]==1)
}
```

or this:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(sttbl)) {
     sttbl[i,4]=cpquery(fit, sttbl[i,1] == 1, sttbl[i,2] == 1)
}
```

Now I think I misunderstood something in R or bnlearn package.

Could you please tell me how to realize this task with filling the column by multiple cpqueries? That would help me a lot with my research!

Comment: Hi, can you show how you are trying to automate this please (as the code you show works)

Comment: @user20650 I was completely sure I am mistaken, so I've deleted all my attempts. Although I remembered 2 examples and completed the question by them.

Comment: thanks Alex; I'll post something.it is difficult to use  bnlearn inference tools in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cpquery` is quite difficult to work with programmatically. If you look at the examples in the help page you can see the author uses `eval(parse(...))` to build the queries. I have added two approaches below, one using the methods from the help page and one using `cpdist` to draw samples and reweighting to get the probabilities.

Your example

```
library(bnlearn); library(dplyr)
data(learning.test)
baynet = hc(learning.test)
fit = bn.fit(baynet, learning.test)
sttbl = arc.strength(x = baynet, data = learning.test)
sttbl = sttbl %>% mutate(prob = NA) %>% arrange(strength)
```

This uses `cpquery` and the much maligned `eval(parse(...))` -- this is the
approach the the `bnlearn` author takes to do this programmatically in the `?cpquery` examples. Anyway,

```
# You want the evidence and event to be the same; in your question it is `1`
# but for example using learning.test data we use 'a'
state = "\'a\'" # note if the states are character then these need to be quoted
event = paste(sttbl$from, "==", state)
evidence = paste(sttbl$to, "==", state)

# loop through using code similar to that found in `cpquery`
set.seed(1) # to make sampling reproducible
for(i in 1:nrow(sttbl)) {
  qtxt = paste("cpquery(fit, ", event[i], ", ", evidence[i], ",n=1e6", ")")
  sttbl$prob[i] = eval(parse(text=qtxt))
}
```

I find it preferable to work with `cpdist` which is used to generate random samples conditional on some evidence. You can then use these samples to build up queries. If you use likelihood weighting (`method="lw"`) it is slightly easier to do this programatically (and without `evil(parse(...))`).
The evidence is added in a named list i.e. `list(A='a')`.

```
# The following just gives a quick way to assign the same
# evidence state to all the evidence nodes.  
evidence = setNames(replicate(nrow(sttbl), "a", simplify = FALSE), sttbl$to)

# Now loop though the queries
# As we are using likelihood weighting we need to reweight to get the probabilities
# (cpquery does this under the hood)
# Also note with this method that you could simulate from more than
# one variable (event) at a time if the evidence was the same.
for(i in 1:nrow(sttbl)) {
  temp = cpdist(fit, sttbl$from[i], evidence[i], method="lw")
  w = attr(temp, "weights")  
  sttbl$prob2[i] = sum(w[temp=='a'])/ sum(w)
}

sttbl
#   from to   strength      prob     prob2
# 1    A  D -1938.9499 0.6186238 0.6233387
# 2    A  B -1153.8796 0.6050552 0.6133448
# 3    C  D  -823.7605 0.7027782 0.7067417
# 4    B  E  -720.8266 0.7332107 0.7328657
# 5    F  E  -549.2300 0.5850828 0.5895373
```

Comment: your methods work perfectly well for my binary data! (as you noticed c:). However, when I try to make it function with _sttbl_ and _fit_ as variables (to make the loop applicable for different cases via one function) it's not working. Here what I tried: 
`probs = function(sttable, fittedbn){
  evidence = setNames(replicate(nrow(sttable), "1", simplify = FALSE), sttable$to)
for(i in 1:nrow(sttable)) {
  temp = cpdist(fittedbn, sttable$from[i], evidence[i], method="lw")
  w = attr(temp, "weights")  
  sttable$prob[i] = sum(w[temp==1])/ sum(w)}}`. Nothing happenes.

Comment: R does not update by reference so you need to return `sttable` i.e. add `return(sttable)` before the final parenthesis

Comment: ... although I think id maybe return the vector of probabilities and 
assign this to the data set. That is change the relevant lines to 
`prob[i]=sum(w[temp==1])/ sum(w)  } ;  return(prob)` and then run the 
function and assign it with `sttable$prob = probs(sttable, fit)`